# GUI patterns for CRUD web applications

Tags: user-interface, crud, interaction-design

This is a vague question about user experience and interaction design patterns (not programming) for CRUD web applications.

Let there are few simple entities, e.g. `Student`, `Course`, and `Lecturer` with obvious relations.

As I understand, a CRUD application usually provides a screen per entity to browse entities, update, remove them, and add a new one. The screen may provide also a search box.

The application GUI uses relations to display entity-related information (e.g. courses per student) and navigate from one entity screen to another (e.g. from a `Student's` course name in the `Student` screen to the `Course` description in the `Course` screen).

Does it make sense ? Are there other GUI patterns for CRUD applications ? What example would you recommend to learn from ?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds logical enough to me. There are some GUI patterns here :

http://www.welie.com/patterns/

http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/

Comment: +1, and there's also a collection of patterns from Tidwell's book at http://designinginterfaces.com/ -- mostly those patterns that deal with complex data in your case, though.

Answer (score 1):

the frameworks like rails generate some scaffolding pages to add /delete/modify the model objects, i'd suggest you to have a look at it .

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly... **view models** is a concept that allows you to add customized groups of data. Scaffholding etc. would be just a means of quickly generating the data to display on screen. Are you using Asp.net Mvc, Ruby or PHP?

Comment: I am using Java and probably will use JS with some GUI framework.